# Program freezes when reading XML

Tags: c#, xml

This is my code:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("test.xml"))
{          
    int prev = ' ';
    List<string> info = new List<string>();
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();

    for (int c; (c = reader.Read()) != -1; )
    {
        if (prev == '>' && c != '<')
        {
            while (c != '<')
            {
                if (c != ' ' && c != '\n' && c != '\r' && c != '\t') temp.Append((char)c);
                c = reader.Read();
            }

            if (temp.Length > 0)
            {
                info.Add(temp.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString());
                temp.Clear();
            }
        }
        prev = c;
    }

    foreach (string item in info) Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

I'm trying to read the meaningful content (the info between tags) from an XML file (without methods implemented in .NET). The program seems to read the data chunks and put them in a list successfully, but when it reaches the end of file it just freezes without executing the remaining code after the for statement. I must say that it isn't looping anymore - I tried that, it just freezes.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"><student><name>Pesho</name>
<age>21</age><interests count="3"><interest>
Games</instrest><interest>C#</instrest><interest>
Java</instrest></interests></student>
```

Comment: Can you add a part of your XML file?

Comment: I edited my post. My idea is to read it char by char instead of line by line.

Comment: Why don't you read it with a XML parser?

Comment: Why don't you paste your code into this question? You can have good formatting of code in a question here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @John, the idea of the exercise is to create some kind of algorithms no matter how simpple they are instead of using ready .NET libraries. :)

Comment: I don't have any problem executing our code.

Comment: Really? Which version of VS are you using? Mine is 2012. It doesn't execute foreach (string item in info) Console.WriteLine(item); line the other prints are just for testing and are from Console.WriteLine(temp.ToString());

Comment: @RosenDimov I think reading XML is not a great choice for such exercise.

Comment: @svick, i have to do it no matter how appopriate it is :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the inner-most loop, the `while` loop, can keep reading from the stream forever becasue it reads `while (c != '<')`, and `(-1) != '<'`.

Note that when you use the operator `!=` between an `int` (`-1`) and a `char` (`'<'`), the latter is automatically converted to `int`, so it really reads:

```
while (c != 60)
```

Comment: thanks, that was the problem indeed. There was a '\n' sign in the end which was the trouble.